# How to Query 4 Pivot Tables

Tags: sql, pivot

Could you help me to check as below:

```
DECLARE @tblCity TABLE (CityID INT, CityName VARCHAR(100))  
DECLARE @tblHotel TABLE (HotelID INT, HotelName VARCHAR(100)) 
DECLARE @tblTourClass TABLE (TourClassID INT, TourClass VARCHAR(100)) 
DECLARE @tblTourHotel TABLE (id INT, CityID INT, HotelID INT, TourClassID INT) 

INSERT INTO @tblCity SELECT 1, 'Phnom Penh' UNION SELECT 2, 'Siem Reap' UNION SELECT 3, 'Sihanouk Vill'
INSERT INTO @tblHotel SELECT 1, 'City Angkor Hotel' UNION SELECT 2, 'Phnom Penh Hotel' UNION SELECT 3, 'Sihanouk Ville Hotel' UNION SELECT 4, 'New York Hotel' UNION SELECT 5, 'Pacific Hotel' UNION SELECT 6, 'Angkor Star Hotel' UNION SELECT 7, 'Khemera Angkor Hotel' UNION SELECT 8, 'Sokha beach Hotel' UNION SELECT 9, 'Costle Hotel'
INSERT INTO @tblTourClass SELECT 1, 'Deluxe Class' UNION SELECT 2, 'Superior Class' UNION SELECT 3, 'Standard Class'
INSERT INTO @tblTourHotel SELECT 1, 1, 2, 1 UNION SELECT 2, 2, 1, 1 UNION SELECT 3,3,3,1 UNION SELECT 4,1,4,2 UNION SELECT 5,1,5,3 UNION SELECT 6,2,6,2 UNION SELECT 7,2,7,3 UNION SELECT 8,3,8,2 UNION SELECT 9,3,9,3
```

Here's the actual query:

```
SELECT CityName, [Deluxe Class], [Superior Class], [Standard Class]
FROM
(
SELECT tc.*, h.*, c.* 
FROM @tblTourClass tc 
    LEFT JOIN @tblTourHotel th ON tc.TourClassID = th.TourClassID 
    LEFT JOIN @tblCity c ON th.CityID = c.CityID 
    LEFT JOIN @tblHotel h ON th.HotelID = h.HotelID
) AS sourcetable
PIVOT 
(   MAX(HotelName) 
  FOR TourClass IN ([Deluxe Class], [Superior Class], [Standard Class]) 
) AS pivottable
WHERE CityName IS NOT NULL
```

And the results:

```
 City Name       Deluxe Class            Superior    First   Standard
 Siem Reap       City Angkor Hotel       NULL    NULL    NULL
 Phnom Penh      Phnom Penh Hotel        NULL    NULL    NULL
 Sihanouk Vill   Sihanouk Ville Hotel    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

But I want to display as bellow:

```
 City Name   Deluxe Class      Superior           Standard 
 Siem Reap   CityAngkor Hotel  Angkor Star Hotel  Khemera Angkor Hotel 
 Phnom Penh  Phnom Penh Hotel  New York Hotel     Pacific Hotel  
 Sihanouk    Sihanouk Hotel    Sokha beach Hotel  Costle Hotel
```

Could you help me to do how to display as above.

many thanks

Comment: What database? What version?? Can you please describe what it is you're trying to achieve??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  pvt.CityName,
  pvt.[Deluxe Class],
  pvt.[Superior Class],
  pvt.[Standard Class]
FROM ( 
SELECT
  c
  .CityName,
  h.HotelName,
  tc.TourClass
FROM @tblCity c
LEFT JOIN @tblTourHotel th ON c.CityID = th.CityID
LEFT JOIN @tblHotel h ON th.HotelID = h.HotelID
LEFT JOIN @tblTourClass tc ON th.TourClassID = tc.TourClassID
) t
PIVOT (
  MAX(HotelName)
  FOR TourClass IN ([Deluxe Class], [Superior Class], [Standard Class])
) AS pvt
```

It looks like the by using `SELECT tc.*, h.*, c.*`, the computation of the aggregate value became a problem. But I also rearranged the query so that @tblCity is the basis for all the LEFT JOINS.

Comment: Dear Sir

many thanks for your help, the problem has been solve.

Comment: Hello, One More 

I want to display on asp.net so how can I do.

Comment: I would pose that as a new question with the specifcs of what you need to accomplish.